# Using Javascript with Drupal

Tags: javascript, css, drupal

I have a website, http://raptorshop.com

Currently, I have set the CSS to have a min-height of 700px, however I would like for every page to automatically note the size of the browser, and resize accordingly (so that the footer has about 50-200px depending on browser size, but nothing more). Currently, if you browse to the site on a small monitor, it gives a scroll, which I do not want.

Is there a way to do this in Drupal? I know how to do it for individual pages, but I want every page to do this sort of automatic check/resize.

Comment: What CSS is set to 700px? What is the expected result?

Comment: P.S. It sounds like you might need to use `max-height` instead of `min-height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the window height with jquery pretty easily, then change the css as needed.
An example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($(window).height() < 700) 
  {
    // this window is smaller than 700px 
  }
  else
  {
    // this window is bigger than 700px
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to edit some template files, such as those for the site's header and footer. In those, it sounds like what you really want to implement is a CSS Sticky Footer.

You can get one of those here: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/